# Was there an autocomplete utility in MS-DOS?

Tags: ms-dos, software-recommendation, shell

MS-DOS (at least 6.22) had optional features such as `DOSKEY` to remember the command line history, which is now standard on modern command prompts. However, I'm not aware of an autocomplete feature, such as on modern systems by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Was there a Microsoft supplied or third party utility for autocomplete on MS-DOS?

Answer (score 23):

Microsoft didn’t provide anything like this for MS-DOS, but there are a number of third-party tools which can add auto-completion to the shell (along with other command-line editing features). A number of these are listed in [the `DOSKEY` replacement section](http://www.reimagery.com/fsfd/keyb.htm#cleditors) of the Free Software for DOS catalog: Toddy, CmdEdit, etc.

[4DOS](https://www.4dos.info/) and [FreeCOM](http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/FreeCOM), which are full shell replacements (the latter for FreeDOS, and somewhat anachronistic if you’re asking specifically about MS-DOS), have completion support built-in.

Comment: Most CMD.EXE versions for newer Windows systems obviously support TAB completion - But that's not MS-DOS. Also, I've always found CMD's way of cycling through the options instead of displaying them all a bit weird.

Comment: @shoover ...and a healthy part of any effort to free up more conventional memory because it can load itself high more thoroughly than `COMMAND.COM` despite all the extra features.

Answer (score 3):

Paul Houle wrote a version of doskey with autocompletion.  I currently have it loaded under IBMDOS 5.00, but it works under other DOS versions as well.

http://www.paulhoule.com/doskey/

Answer (score 2):

Norton Command for DOS had both a command line history and a feature to quickly paste filenames into the command line: Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and a letter would jump to the next file starting with that letter, more letters would refine the search prefix, or one could move to other files with the arrow keys. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl-Enter</kbd> would then paste the highlighted file into the command line.

While this is not exactly tab-completion, in practice it was very very similar. So I guess that would count as a third-party utility.

It wasn't uncommon to do all file system work completely in Norton Commander anyway (at least that's what I did).

Comment: Yes, I did this too. For readers not familiar with NC, it handled a command line too, and could be used like the DOS prompt with a file manager on top.

Answer (score 0):

[DR-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DR-DOS), which was not MS-DOS but which was, by design, largely compatible at many levels, and was a contemporaneous single-user Intel CPU based system operating system, included command-line history and, IIRC, some search/autocomplete functionality. Unfortunately, I don't have any running systems to check the specifics now (well, for many years...). At least the basic command-line history was very nice - having just MS-DOS's one line (F3 - wow, just checked and that still works in the Windows 7 CMD) after learning to program on bigger systems was quite annoying.

Comment: Nah. DR-Dos didn't know command line completion.

Comment: I just checked on DR DOS 6 and OpenDOS 7, and they don’t support completion, even with `HISTORY` set to `ON`. (They do provide much better line editing than plain MS-DOS, including incremental search through history entries.)